# Maven - File Inclusion/Exclusion regexp syntax rules

Tags: regex, maven

I would like to know more about the "regular Expression" [1] syntax that is used in Maven plus other build tools like Ant, Grunt and so on.

Consider the snippet below - specifically the two **`<include>`** directives to specify the

- directory
- subdirectory
- file name(s)

to be included/excluded

```
 <project>
      ...
      <name>My Resources Plugin Practice Project</name>
      ...
      <build>
        ...
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/my-resources</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>**/*.txt</include>
              <include>**/*.rtf</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
          ...
        </resources>
        ...
      </build>
      ...
    </project>
```

Is there any documentation available on an exhaustive list of rules? I could not find anything (other than the examples provided) on this specific syntax. Rather I am forced to rely upon trial and error (rather than concrete understanding and reasoning).

**Footnote:**
1. I say "Regular Expression" - in a broad sense here. These syntax rules do not seem to be compatible with Perl5/6 Regular Expression syntax. So, I am assuming it is a different regex dialect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are [Ant patterns](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns).

> *.java  matches  .java, x.java and FooBar.java, but not FooBar.xml
>   (does not end with .java).
>
> ?.java  matches  x.java, A.java, but not .java or xyz.java (both don't
>   have one character before .java).
>
> ...
>
> When ** is used as the name of a directory in the pattern, it matches zero or more directories.