# Regex as maven-clean-plugin parameter

Tags: regex, maven

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>BqGmGzjrjKwS</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

In directory I would like to regex that matches alphabetic string with 12 digits - anyone could help ? Maven supports regex in pom ?

Case is that after each build (cucumber test) the directory with 12 characters alphabetical string is created (example above in directory) - I want to delete it.

Comment: You have _BqGmGzjrjKwS_ do you mean `characters` instead of `digits`? And what is the problem you need to solve? Do you have for example N directories each named with arbitrary set of 12 chars which you need to delete on clean or what?

Comment: Why do you need such thing? What is the problem behind this?

Comment: Each run of cucumber test creates a directory which name matches 12 digits alphabetical string. I want to delete it.

Comment: `clean` deletes all directories unter `target`. Why do you need special handling for this one?

Comment: Directories are created under main project - not in target.

Comment: Then it would be the right thing to reconfigure the cucumber tests so that they create their directories in target.

Comment: If you cannot configure cucmber to make it on target, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591590/maven-file-inclusion-exclusion-regexp-syntax-rules). I guess it could be possible using 12x `?` but of course there should not be any other directories of length 12 unde project root dir. And: not sure if clean plugin supports.

Comment: Unfortunately seems that maven-celan-plugin do not supports regular expression :(  Any other ideas ... ?